# Youtube API : Get the View count of a particular song title

Tags: python, youtube-api

I have a dataset of about 20,000 songs for which I need to get youtube video views. My current approach is :

1. For each search string ( a song name in this scenario), I first get the list of video id's through search_list_by_keyword API ( i would ideally like to get the best 10 videos but for now let's assume it's 1).
2. For this video id, i hit the second API, videos_list_by_id which gives me the statistics of that video.

   The above operation has a quota cost of 103 which implies I can at max get about 87 such values in 24 hours. So is this in the first place the right way to do this? If not, what is and if yes, is there any workaround to getting this data for 20k songs ?

Comment: From your approach, I think that will be the only solution you can do. There's no certain API with only one call for this case.

Comment: Can you add a sample of the 20,000 songs? do you have this info by video title or its videoId?, add also in your question the parameters of the requests you're using currently. I'm saying this because, *(if you reduce the variables)*, it *might* be poissible get a more results (not 20,000 of course)...

Comment: Also note you can request up to 50 videos at a time, greatly reducing quota costs.